# Why does CosmosDB ignore indexes when creating document collection via ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

Given the ARM template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "1test2/sql/2test3/3test4",
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "3test4",
          "indexingPolicy": {
            "indexingMode": "Consistent",
            "includedPaths": [
              {
                  "path": "/definition/property/?",
                  "indexes": [
                    {
                        "kind": "Range",
                        "dataType": "String"
                    }
                ]
              }
          ],
            "excludedPaths": [
            {
                "path": "/*"
            }
        ]
          },
          "partitionKey": {
            "paths": [
              "/definition/id"
            ],
            "kind": "Hash"
          },
        },
        "options": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When deployed to an existing CosmosDB database using the PowerShell command 
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment, the resulting indexing settings are:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/definition/property/?",
            "indexes": []
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

So whilst CosmosDB accepts the 'includedPaths', it ignores the 'indexes'. Am I doing something wrong or is that expected?

Comment: the only difference I can see with [official example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/manage-sql-with-resource-manager#create-resource) is `"precision": -1` for the indexes

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks - but I have tried it with precision too (my original document had that in) but I removed it to keep the repro as simple as possible.

Comment: try using the same apiversion: `"apiVersion": "2016-03-31",`

Comment: actually, official example doesn't seem to set those properties, lol

Comment: Tried it with the suggested apiVersion but still no dice :-(

Comment: yeah, I just tried the official example, indexes are not being set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent changes have been made to the Cosmos DB indexing engine that defaults to range index for both strings and numbers with a precision of -1.

The ARM templates and docs have not yet been updated to reflect this as the default values.

If non-default changes are made to the indexing policy, e.g., adding a spatial index, they will be included in the deployed container.

Comment: I wondered if there was something like that going on. Thanks for confirming.